How to build external URL with parameters in flask/jinja2?
Simple question, how can I build URL with parameters for external websites?
Flask helper url_for is really handy to build internal links and I was wandering if it could also be used for external links, but it seems that this is not as simple as it sounds.
<a href="{{ url_for('endpoint', foo='bar') }}">internal</a>
<a href="{{ url_for('https://example.net/', foo='bar', _external=true) }}">external (doesn't work)</a>

from flask import Flask, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SERVER_NAME"] = "example.com"
app.config["PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME"] = "https"

with app.app_context():
    # Expected: "https://example.net/?foo=bar"
    print(url_for("https://example.net/", foo="bar", _external=True))

url_for has _external option, but it seems different from what I imagined.

Edit
I currently use urlencode filter to build parameters:
<a href="https://example.net/?{{ dict(foo='bar') | urlencode }}">external link</a>


It is possible to add an external url directly within flasks route map with app.add_url_rule("/", endpoint="www.example.com", host="www.example.com", build_only=True) however this requires host_matching=True to be set when creating your application object and this could potentially interfere with how the routing works for your internal routes. I would suggest setting up a separate route map for your external routes by using the werkzeug Map and Rule objects directly.
from werkzeug.routing import Map, Rule

class UrlExternal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = Map([Rule('/', host="www.example.com", endpoint="com_root"),
                        Rule('/api/<int:val>', host="www.example.net" ,endpoint="net_api")],
                       host_matching=True)
        self.adapter = self.map.bind("", url_scheme="https")

    def __call__(self, endpoint, **values):
        return self.adapter.build(endpoint, values, force_external=True)

url_external = UrlExternal()

print(url_external("com_root", val=8, param="p"))
print(url_external("net_api", val=9, param="q"))


try it this way
pip install Flask requests

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

# Route to send a request to an external API
@app.route('/send-request', methods=['GET'])
def send_request():
    external_api_url = 'https://api.example.com/data'
    response = requests.get(external_api_url)
    return jsonify(response.json())

# Route to receive data from a POST request
@app.route('/receive-data', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    data = request.json
    print("Received data:", data)
    return jsonify({"status": "success", "received_data": data})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-request

curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/receive-data -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key": "value"}'


I need URL with parameters from variables.  redirect returns Response object and can't be used in templates.

in this case use this. i will update

Thanks, but no.  I just wanna build a URL string that can be used with Jinja2 HTML template in the same manner as flask.url_for helper. My question is not about sending/receiving HTTP nor API requests.
